# AngularJS+Jasmine: $httpBackend not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, service, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm using **Jasmine** with **Karma** to test my app built on **Angular**.

I've to test a service that loads user data and I'm using *$httpBackend* to mock the responses.
However, when I run the test, I got two errors:

- **Error: No pending request to flush!**
- **Error: Unsatisfied requests: GET https://api.github.com/users/wilk**

**Module:**

```
'use strict';

app.service ('UserService', ['$resource', '$q', 'GITHUB_API_URL', function ($resource, $q, GITHUB_API_URL) {
  var userResource = $resource (GITHUB_API_URL + '/users/:user', {user: '@user'}) ,
      userModel = {};

  return {
    data: function () {
        return userModel;
    } ,
    populate: function (user) {
      var deferred = $q.defer () ,
          userRequest = userResource.get ({user: user});

      $q
          .when (userRequest.$promise)
          .then (function (data) {
              userModel = data;
              deferred.resolve (data);
          });

      return deferred.promise;
    }
  };
}]);
```

**Test:**

```
'use strict';

describe ('Service: UserService', function () {
    beforeEach (module ('myApp'));

    var $appInjector = angular.injector (['myApp']) ,
        UserService = $appInjector.get ('UserService') ,
        GITHUB_API_URL = $appInjector.get ('GITHUB_API_URL') ,
        GITHUB_USER = $appInjector.get ('GITHUB_USER') ,
        $httpBackend;

    beforeEach (inject (function ($injector) {
        $httpBackend = $injector.get ('$httpBackend');

        $httpBackend
            .when ('GET', GITHUB_API_URL + '/users/' + GITHUB_USER)
            .respond ({
                login: GITHUB_USER ,
                id: 618009
            });
    }));

    afterEach (function () {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation ();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest ();
    });

    describe ('when populate method is called', function () {
        it ('should returns user data', function () {
            $httpBackend.expectGET (GITHUB_API_URL + '/users/' + GITHUB_USER);

            UserService.populate (GITHUB_USER);
            $httpBackend.flush ();
            expect(UserService.data ()).toEqual ({
                login: GITHUB_USER ,
                id: 618009
            });

        });
    });
});
```

Let's assume that GITHUB_API_URL is equal to *'https://api.github.com/'* and GITHUB_USER is equal to *'wilk'*.

I'm running this test with **Karma-Jasmine 0.1.5** and **AngularJS 1.2.6** (with Angular Mocks and Scenario 1.2.6).

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: I created a [Plunker script](http://plnkr.co/edit/hadb1Ko6lPZpMYIE24kC?p=preview) with your code, but I don't know what GITHUB_USER is. Would you mind updating it?

Comment: @MichaelBenford It's a constant and as I mentioned is equal to the string 'wilk'.

Comment: My bad. Didn't notice it.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Let's talk about each error separately:

**Error: No pending request to flush!**

That's happening because no request was made through `$httpBackend`, so there's nothing to flush. That's because you are instantiating `UserService` before `$httpBackend` and so Angular doesn't know it should use it instead of the real `$http`. If you check out the console you'll see that a real request is being sent.

**Error: Unsatisfied requests: GET https://api.github.com/users/wilk**

Same reason as the above. Since `$httpBackend` isn't being used by the service, the expectation you've created is never fulfilled.

Here's your spec refactored after considering all of the above:

```
describe ('Service: UserService', function () {
    var UserService,
        GITHUB_API_URL,
        GITHUB_USER,
        $httpBackend;

    beforeEach(function() {
      module('plunker');

      inject(function( _$httpBackend_, _UserService_, _GITHUB_API_URL_, _GITHUB_USER_) {
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        UserService = _UserService_;
        GITHUB_API_URL = _GITHUB_API_URL_;
        GITHUB_USER = _GITHUB_USER_;
      });
    });

    afterEach (function () {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation ();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest ();
    });

    describe ('when populate method is called', function () {
        it ('should returns user data', function () {
            $httpBackend
              .whenGET(GITHUB_API_URL + '/users/' + GITHUB_USER)
              .respond ({
                  login: GITHUB_USER,
                  id: 618009
              }); 

            UserService.populate(GITHUB_USER);
            $httpBackend.flush();

            expect(UserService.data().login).toBe(GITHUB_USER);
            expect(UserService.data().id).toBe(618009);
        });
    });
});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hadb1Ko6lPZpMYIE24kC?p=preview)

Note: I've changed the way things were being injected a little bit, but the way you are doing is just fine, as long as you create `$httpBackend` before everything else.

Comment: Woah! +1 for the great answer! Clear and detailed! Thanks for the explanation!
However I didn't understand yet how 'inject' function works. How can inject such those renamed params? I mean, how does it know that _UserService_ it's a service of my module?

Comment: @Wilk When you call `module('myApp')` Angular loads all services that module contains so the injector can use any of them. The underscores in the param names are just to prevent variable names from clashing. Angular just ignores them. You don't need to use them if your local variables have different names, though. More info on that [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.mock.inject).

Comment: Thanks so much, if I could +1 this again and again I would. I was pulling my hair out trying to figure out why my requests were unsatisfied.

Comment: I wish I could vote this up again, months ago I was here for the first error, now I found it again for the second error answer lol. Thanks again.

Comment: ummmm, can you elaborate "the expectation you've created is never fulfilled"? I am getting the `Error: Unsatisfied requests: PUT /api/v1/categories/by_key/zoom` error